# Creating seperate assembly for sub namespaces in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, namespaces, .net-assembly

I am coding a web project that references many assemblies. I want to create a separated assembly for a sub namespace that is in root namespace without creating a different project. But i couldn't achieve this. I hope you will help for this problem. I assume , either i can explain  or you are understand me.

Thanks for all.

Comment: "But i couldn't achieve this" is not a good description. What did you try, and what happened?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio compiles each project to a DLL. You cannot build a project and send the output to 2 different dll's.

If you look at the project properties in Visual Studio there is a single field for "Assembly Name"

The simplest solution is to move the code in the sub namespace to a seperate project.